# PJSIP 2.6 | Android | Video call not working

Tags: android, video, sip, pjsip

I have compiled the PJSIP 2.6 for Android but it's not generating Video call its generating only Audio call but I have compiled it for video calls also.

Is OpenSSL also required for normal Video call? (i have not compiled OpenSSL, I have just compiled "libpjsua2.so" & "libopenh264.so")

In INVITE & RESPONSE packet also not having Video information.

Version is: 2.6

Thanks
Anshuman

Comment: Is there any way by which I can check "libpjsua2.so" is supporting video call or not?

Comment: got any solution.Stuck in the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled it again with few more modifications now its initializing openH264.
BUT when am start making call its throwing following error:

pjsua_call.c  Invite session creation failed: No SDP payload format in the media line (PJMEDIA_SDP_ENOFMT) [status=220032]
10-27 18:36:13.326 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.326  pjsua_media.c  Call 0: deinitializing media..
10-27 18:36:13.326 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.326  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: cleaning up provisional media, prov_med_cnt=2, med_cnt=0
10-27 18:36:13.327 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.327        icetp00  .Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
10-27 18:36:13.328 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.327        icetp00  .Destroying ICE session 0x92c73014
10-27 18:36:13.329 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.328        icetp00  ..ICE stream transport 0x98132614 destroyed
10-27 18:36:13.329 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.329  ice_session.c  ..ICE session 0x92c73014 destroyed
10-27 18:36:13.330 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.329        icetp01  .Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
10-27 18:36:13.330 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.330        icetp01  .Destroying ICE session 0x92c74c14
10-27 18:36:13.331 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.330        icetp01  ..ICE stream transport 0x98132c14 destroyed
10-27 18:36:13.331 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:13.331  ice_session.c  ..ICE session 0x92c74c14 destroyed
10-27 18:36:14.333 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:14.332    pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
10-27 18:36:14.334 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:14.333    pjsua_aud.c  .Closing Android JNI sound playback device and Android JNI sound capture device
10-27 18:36:14.334 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:14.334 android_jni_de  .Android JNI stream stopped
10-27 18:36:14.335 30397-30555/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 13:06:14.